# Help with a contradiction I found in an equation group

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following is a homework problem but I seem to find a contradiction in it.

> [image]

**My problem**

By the third equation, $\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial t}} = f'(x + t) - g'(x - t)$, and $\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial t}}(x,0) = f'(x) - g'(x)=0$, thus $f(x) - g(x) = C$ for some constant $C$. Note here $f'(x),g'(x)$ are differentiations with respect to $x$, not $t$.

Together with the second equation, we further have $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1 + C - |x|)$, $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1 - C- |x|)$.

Now by the first equation, $u(1,t) = f(1 + t) + g(1 - t) = \frac{1}{2}(1 + C - |1 + t|) + \frac{1}{2}(1 - C - |1 - t|) = 0$, which gives $|1 + t| + |1 - t| = 2$. **Apparently, this does not hold for all $t>0$**.

Is the problem indeed having some "problem", or I go wrong somewhere in the above calculation? Thank you!

Comment: Two things: you lost a $1$ in your second-to-last step, and you can't combine those absolute values in that way. Specifically, you have $|1+t|=1+t$ for $t>-1$ and $|1-t|=1-t$ for $t<1$. So the whole thing is $3$ for $-1<t<1$. Then you have $2t+1$ for $t>1$ and $-2t+1$ for $t<-1$. That is, provided I did the calculation correctly. EDIT: which I didn't. I missed the 1/2. Also, Ud779's comment.

Comment: For the third equation, be careful as you get $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial t}}-\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial t}}=0$. This does not mean that $f(x)-g(x)=C$. It means $f(x)-g(x)=c(x)$, because you took a partial derivative in terms of $t$.

Comment: @Ud779 Thank you for your reply, but I think your comment is not right. $f(x) - g(x) = C$ is not the result of taking partial differentiation. Check it again. It is the result of $f'(x) - g'(x) = 0$. Here the '`' means differentiation with respect to $x$, not $t$.

Comment: @Ud779 $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial t}} - \frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial t}} = 0$ is not part of my calculation.

Comment: You are right, I misread that $f$ and $g$ were also multivariable functions. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u(x,0)=1-|x|$, given the condition that $x \in [0,1] $, then it is equivalent to say:

$u(x,0)=1-x$, under the same conditions.

This causes the t to cancel out. However that function you derived is only valid at t=0 so the result is unexplained at t>0.

There is something off with this question.

Comment: Right, but when you derived the closed form equations for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, remember that the restriction is still active, wherein $x \in [0,1]$. As soon as you substitute $1+t$ and $1-t$, you are saying that both of these expressions have to be part of the restricted interval simultaneously. However, they are only both valid when $t=0$.